# ASYNC / AWAIT SQL Insert

Tags: node.js, mysql2

I am coding at altv.mp GTA V platform and I have an problem;

When I try do insert some value I get undefined or etc.
(query is correct)

I use await and async and promise for there and this time I get Promise : Pending

How can I get insertID

````
   let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       con.query(query, params, (err, result) => {
           if (err)
               return reject(err);
           resolve(result.insertId);
       });
   });


   let res = await promise;
   console.log(res);
   return res;
}

export function createveh(player, type, idbytype, model) {

   let posX = player.pos.x;
   let posY = player.pos.y + 5;
   let posZ = player.pos.z + 1;
   let rotX = player.rot.x;
   let rotY = player.rot.y;
   let rotZ = player.rot.z;
   let dimension = player.dimension;

   try {
       const newVehicle = new alt.Vehicle(model, posX, posY, posZ, rotX, rotY, rotZ);
       let dimension = newVehicle.dimension;
       let primaryColor = newVehicle.primaryColor;
       let dirtLevel = newVehicle.dirtLevel;
       let engineHealth = newVehicle.engineHealth;
       let lockstate = newVehicle.lockState;
       let modkit = newVehicle.modKit;
       newVehicle.numberPlateText = license();
       let plate = newVehicle.numberPlateText;
       let secondaryColor = newVehicle.secondaryColor;


       alt.emitClient(player, 'vehicle:createveh', newVehicle);
       


       let sqlID;
       let query = "INSERT INTO vehicle SET model = ?, type = ?, owner = ?, posX = ?, posY = ?, posZ = ?, rotX = ?, rotY = ?, rotZ = ?, dimension = ?, primaryColor = ?, dirtLevel = ?, engineHealth = ?, lockState = ?, modKit = ?, plate = ?, secondaryColor = ?";
       let args = [model, type, idbytype, posX, posY, posZ, rotX, rotY, rotZ, dimension, primaryColor, dirtLevel, engineHealth, lockstate, modkit, plate, secondaryColor];
       
       return (async () => {
           return await asynqQuery(query, args);
       })();


      
   } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
   }
   //return insertId;
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql2` module has [inbuilt promise support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper). As your use case doesn't really require your own promise implementation, all you need to do is:

```
export async function createveh(player, type, idbytype, model) {
   ...
   try {
       ...
       const [result] = await con.query(query, args);
       // extract id from result and return it
   } catch (err) {
       console.log(err);
   }
}
```